# Displaying a Dropdown List of All Angular Material Icons in Angular 2+ / 10

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

I'm working on an Angular 10 application and using Angular Material Icons. I'm looking for a way to dynamically display a dropdown list containing all the available Material Icons.

I've attempted to retrieve the list programmatically using MatIconRegistry, but so far, the icons array remains empty. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
    this.matIconRegistry['_iconSetConfigs'].forEach((config: any) => {
        if (config.names) {
            config.names.forEach((name: string) => {
                const sanitizedUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(config.url);
                ics.push(name);
            });
        }
    });
```

Is there a reliable approach to fetch the list of Material Icons and display them in a dropdown in Angular 10?

Any insights or alternative solutions would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Trying to build something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may not want to display all the material icons in a dropdown as there are more than 900. Angular doesn't provide an API to get the list programmatically but here are [the codes for them.](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/material-design-icons/master/font/MaterialIcons-Regular.codepoints)

Note that lately they went [for the font route](https://fonts.google.com/icons):

> Material Symbols are our newest icons, consolidating over 2,500 glyphs
> in a single font.

Ideally you would have a list of the desired icons and use the [approach suggested by Kenedy.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77619181/2150342)

Comment: yes, I need all of them, because Users should be able to search for and select any possible icon. My project uses hundreds of icons, support guys should create documentation for each feature (via UI), each feature has a lot of icons, and those icons should have some description that fits its responsibility.
The project is in active development, count of icons will rise over time, so it will be hard to support such an approach. It is better to have one single list and show all of them.
I believe there is some solution to getting all those icons.

Thank you for the given list.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to display the icon from the material, you can do it like this

```html
<div *ngFor="let icon of icons;">
<mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon" [fontIcon]="icon"></mat-icon>
</div>
```

```js
icons = ['home']
```

```js
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';

@NgModule({
  imports: [MatIconModule]
})
```

Comment: how do you fetch all the icons? I also can add one icon